# Phonegap uploaded audio file not being played in browser

Tags: audio, upload, cordova, streaming, recording

I am uploading a recorded mp3 file using phonegap and php

Recording - Using Media object (media.startRecord/ media.stopRecord) - Successful

Uploading -
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
In options, I am using options.mimeType = "audio/mpeg";

-This is also successful

Playing - But when I try to play it in browser as http://some.server.com/media_uploaded.mp3 - It tries to play but fails after sometime. I tried playing the same file with http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all as well, but couldn't succeed.

When I download the same file - it gets played without any error in any media player in my computer.

When I upload any mp3 song at same place - it gets played successfully with - http://some.server.com/song_uploaded.mp3

What can be possible problem(s) with my recorded audio?

**Update**

Just noticed that problem has nothing to do with 'Upload'. The saved mp3 (when copied to PC) seems to run fine on my computer but not on browser (Even locally - I checked with Audio tag as well). So there is something wrong with the recorded mp3. Not sure what is the solution.

Not working - http://xpertvisions.com/test/media_recorded.mp3

Working - http://xpertvisions.com/test/media_song.mp3

Comment: @blrbr No. The only solution which I have till date is - once file gets uploaded to server, use ffmpeg or any other to convert that sound to mp3 file. After that it becomes playable. But, it works if web hosting service provider provides ffmpeg as a service. Otherwise, one needs to install ffmpeg which is complex/impossible to install on shared hosting - VPS is required for that.

Comment: Check out my answer. I am using C# but there may be a similar solution for PHP. No install necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this that I answered here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/23140836/902630

This is, however, a .Net solution. But looking at it may help lead you in the right direction.